# Is it possible to swap staging to production without downtime?

Tags: azure, sitecore

I've got a sitecore CD set up in an App Service. "production" is "Standard: 2 small" at the moment. In addition I've got a staging slot set up.

My piplines are first build then deploy to staging. At this point I manually verify that both staging and production slots are up and running without error. Response time at this point is about 1 sek.

I then run a "swap" on the slots. This operation takes about 2 minutes. I then hit the production again and it is down, so we have to wait 2-3 minutes for warm up.

Is it possible to swap without actual downtime?

Comment: You might want to look into application initialization. It allows you to specify endpoints that will be hit before the swap is completed. This allows you to prime caches for example.

Comment: https://ruslany.net/2015/09/how-to-warm-up-azure-web-app-during-deployment-slots-swap/ tells us "Then the site in the staging slot gets warmed up. To warm up the site an HTTP request is made to the root directory of the site to every VM instance where site is supposed to run." but why then does hitting the root after swap takes 1.5 minute?

Comment: It probably means your app is still loading something.

Comment: But isn't the point of warmup that it's done before the swap is finalized? I thougt it should be possible with 0 downtime using swap slots, testing so far gives 1-3 minutes downtime

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Preventing staging site restart during a swap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45077899/preventing-staging-site-restart-during-a-swap)

Comment: That is certainly something to look into